# Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen.6 (2018) touchpad and trackpoint issues with linux

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I am having trouble to get my touchpad to work. It does not detect movement or clicks most of the time, and will only very sporadically "wake up", respond for ~one second and then stop. The same applies to the trackpoint. I have tried Fedora (27), Mint and Ubuntu (17.10) and the issue is the same in all versions. Everything that follows is w.r.t. Ubuntu 17.10.

`hwinfo` gives `Unique ID: AH6Q.Y_f5kDtfqz2`

The touchpad does not show up in `xinput`: (it did in Mint, but the problem was also present there). Using `libinput debug-events`, I get:

```
(...)
-event5 DEVICE_ADDED SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad seat0 default group9 cap:pg size 70x50
(...)
(When swiping around on the touchpad, nothing happens. Then, suddenly, it will show:)
-event6 DEVICE_ADDED PS/2 Generic Mouse seat0 default group11 cap:p left scroll-nat scroll-button
-event5 POINTER_MOTION +7.73s 2.98/ 0.00
(...)
- event5 POINTER_MOTION +7.88s 2.54/ 0.00
(and it will cut out again. When continuing swiping, once the keyboard "wakes up" again, the process repeats.)
```

What I believe to the a good hint so far was the result from dmesg. This gives the error `psmouse serio1: TouchPad at isa0060/serio1/input0 lost sync at byte 1` multiple times.

I have found two ways to circumvent the problem, but both are not satisfactory:

1) `modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse proto=imps` will make the touchpad respond, but disables any gestures (two-finger scrolling etc). It also removes the touchpad from the "Settings > Devices > Mouse and touchpad" panel. `sudo libinput list-devices` confirms that most of the functionality is lost.

2) Disabling the trackpoint in the BIOS also leads to the touchpad working as intended, including two-finger scrolling. It does, however, also disable the physical buttons for the touchpad.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am experiencing the same symptoms. The physical buttons just bellow space is part of the trackpoint, which is why they are disabled. Still a pain though.
Unfortunately it is not possible to get the trackpoint to work by disabling the trackpad.
The two physi

Comment: Did you get the model with NFC?

Answer (score 12):

I also have the model with NFC and the following got both trackpoint and touchpad (with 2-finger scrolling) working:

1. Delete (or comment out) the line `i2c_i801` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
2. Add `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=...` line in `/etc/default/grub` (caveat: will be reset and needs to be redone after every kernel update).
3. `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot.

Running Ubuntu 17.10 and kernel 4.16.0

Thanks to user net_life on the [Lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Troubles-with-X1-Carbon-2018-X1C6-TouchPad-and-TrackPoint-under-Linux/m-p/4004815?page=3#4056434)

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me, Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.15.

Comment: Can confirm this for the NFC-Variant on ubuntu, while the non-NFC variant works out of the box on arch linux.

Comment: NFC-variant works out of the box with Ubuntu 18.04 and the mainline kernel 4.17, as well (Touchpad + Trackpoint and multi-finger gestures). I tried Debian before but there's currently no support for `CONFIG_RMI4` in their kernel and I didn't want to build my own.

Comment: The Ubuntu kmod package includes a `blacklist i2c_i801` line in that file, but this actually didn't work for me with Debian's 4.18 kernel, not until I replaced the underscore with the hyphen, to more strictly match the kernel module name.

Comment: April 2020, worked on Linux Mint 19.3 but after I installed the synaptic drivers for the touchpad (this is recommended in the release notes).

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem.

I Have tried with Arch Linux, Ubuntu LTS 16.04, as well as Mint 18.3.

Luckily I have a friend running Arch on a X1 Carbon 6th gen, without pointer-problems.

The only two differences is that we bought different displays, and I bought the model with NFC.  He didn't. 
The NFC is part of the trackpad/trackpoint,
so I think it's down to the lack of drivers for this model.

My machine:

```
$ egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices 
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=synaptics-pt/serio0/input0
```

Sometime only `N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`. With trackpoint disabled in BIOS, always only this entry.

On the X1, where the pointers work:

```
$ egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
N: Name="TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint"
P: Phys=synaptics-pt/serio0/input0
```

So if your machine is is equipped with an NFC receiver as well (there will be a small symbol beneath the trackpoint middle button), instead of the standard pointing devices.

Then I think it is fair to say that this is where the problem lies.

BTW: I am opening a case with Lenovo Monday to see what they can do.

Comment: This seems to be my problem as well. The solution in the thinkpad forum: disable trackpoint in bios + kernal option worked for me, but I can't use the trackpoint anymore.

Comment: @nemo please try commenting out the `i2c_i801` line from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. This was the missing piece for me (as per https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Troubles-with-X1-Carbon-2018-X1C6-TouchPad-and-TrackPoint-under/m-p/4056434/highlight/true#M10826)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to enable all CONFIG_RMI4 kernel options and boot with psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1.

Comment: Hi, can you explain how you "enable all CONFIG_RMI4" kernel options?

Comment: After a very long quest, enabling RMI4 modules in the kernel is the only thing that worked (no modprobe blacklist and no `psmouse.synaptics_intertouch=1` boot option). @nemo you need to compile the kernel with this option, I think this depends on your distro

Answer (score 0):

This is a working method that seems most straightforward to me, using the least invasive initramfs modification method, on Debian 9:

1. Make sure you have [the backports repository](https://backports.debian.org/) set up, e.g.:

   ```
   echo deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install newer kernel:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -t stretch-backports linux-image-amd64
   ```
3. Prepare a custom module config file, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo -e /etc/modprobe.d/local-fix-x1-mouse.conf
   ```
4. Make sure the one conflicting module is out, and the right options are applied on the mouse module:

   ```
   blacklist i2c-i801
   options psmouse synaptics_intertouch=1 proto=exps
   ```
5. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
6. `sudo reboot`

I'm using this with kernel 4.18 now.